# Converting spaces to tabs in multiple files Sublime Text 2

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2, indentation, sublimetext, spaces

Is there any way to convert all spaces to tabs, not file by file?

If I open a file and go through `View => Indentation => Convert Indentation to Tabs`, it only changes this file. I want to convert indentations to tabs in a whole project.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [search and replace in multiple files](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html) to convert `n` spaces to tabs in select files.

First open find in files panel, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, by default to find and replace in multiple files. Next define a regular expression to match spaces as tabs eg  `{4}` (make sure you set *Regular Expressions* in the panel) for 4 spaces and replace with `\t` in desired files. Change `{4}` to however many spaces are being used for indentation.

As mentioned in comments to match spaces at the start of a line you can use the regexp `^( {4})+`

Comment: @moss what part of it doesnt work? Its a simple enough method just make sure you change ` {4}` to however many spaces youre using per indent

Comment: For me ST wants a confirm save on every file, it opened every one of them in tabs (thousands of them) during the operation. Had to use taks manager and kill ST because couldn't close it without confirming thousands of times. Also forgot to omit the quotes around " {4}" (I'm trying the opposite, tabs to spaces) so basically hosed the project but am just testing now so no harm no foul. Maybe should include that in the answer about not literally putting the quotes.

Comment: Ok I found under 'file' in the menu "save all" then follow that with "close all" Also fixed the above mentioned 'hosed project' by turning off regex and replacing the literal " {4}" with a literal 4 spaces and all is good now. As for converting tabs to spaces it took me a while to find. \s in the 'replace' box puts a literal "\s". I found when regex is turned on the replace should be 4 spaces followed by $1 to replace the matched \t with 4 spaces. Also this method doesn't allow choosing file types so it will convert all files under the 'where' box. Something you might not want to do.

Comment: @isimmons you can specify an include filter in the find replace via `*.{js,txt}` (for instance) in the where which will only include javascript and text files. Probably should of mentioned save all in the answer good point

Comment: Works just as well the other way around, eg. (regex) search for `\t` and replace with two spaces

Comment: But doesn't this match 4 spaces anywhere, instead of just the beginning of the line of code? For example if you have a string that has 4 spaces, this will replace that too, no? Is there a regex that matches only the beginning spaces?

Comment: @laggingreflex use `^( {4})+`

Comment: `^( {4})+` will replace _all_ leading sets of four spaces with _one_ tab. Repeatedly replacing `^(\t*)( {2})` with `\1\t` until there are no matches works, but it's not great.

Comment: @isimmons you can save them all in File / Save All